# Can I reprocess jars of salsa that didn't seal

Tags: canning

I made salsa last night and this morning all jars didn't seal.
Can I just put new lids on them and put them back in hot water bath?

Comment: Related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/85300

Answer (score 4):

Per Joe, the [answer about jam jars that didn't seal](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85300/jars-didnt-seal?noredirect=1&lq=1) applies to you as well.

Given that the salsa has now sat out all night unrefrigerated, it would not be safe to re-do the canning process.  If you had checked them immediately, you could probably have used new lids, cleaned the rims of the jars, and hot-water-bathed them again.  But not after 8-12 hours at room temperature.  If they have very high acidity (PH less than 4.0) they might be fine, but why take a chance?

Instead, I suggest putting those jars in the fridge and eating them yourself within the next few days, checking them for bubbles that indicate that the salsa is going off.

Comment: I find your answer internally inconsistent. Why should they be unsafe for re-sterilizing but not for eating within a couple of days? Also, you actually disagree with the answer about jams, because it states that "Canning "rule-of-thumb" is that things can be reprocessed/eaten/refrigerated within 24 hours of the processing and considered safe."

Comment: Because if you're re-canning them, then you're planning to keep them for a long period at room temperature, not just a couple days in the fridge.

Comment: You're right about the Jams answer though, I'd missed the 24 hour bit

Answer (score 1):

A significant aspect of what you accomplish by boiling the jars the length of time you do (1 HR +, if my memory serves me correctly) is cooking as well as sterilizing the contents.
While you could clean, reheat, etc and get the jars to seal, I would think the consistency of the salsa after being cooked twice would be more like tomato paste and less like salsa.